# Displaying Files and Directories and moving them in Java

Tags: java, file, user-interface, filesystems, directory

I want to create an application that moves selected files within the local file system directories to another 'pre-selected location' and back to the directory it came from. I'd like it to be visual so for example I have a JFrame. Inside this JFrame is 2 'windows' one is the current local file system from /home or wherever and it has folders that when you click on them show their sub folders and files that can be clicked on etc (like you would if you open up explorer in windows or finder in mac). The other window to the right is an empty directory already pre selected showing no files inside it.

Between these windows is two buttons. one has an '->' arrow. the Other '<-' These buttons will take the 'selected' directory or file from window 1 and move it to window 2 (behind the visual process the actual files and or directory (including all sub directories) are moved to this location). The <- button puts them back when they were.

a simple enough gui but I'm not sure how to begin coding this or what approach would be best in regards to displaying all the files and having them be selected.

Any ideas?

Euden

Comment: the Java Swing Tutorial should be a good start place (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Comment: See also the [file browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) for some tips.  *"Any ideas?"*  Code simpler things.

Answer (score 0):

For file moving, consider using `renameTo` method in `File` class. Your code should be something like,

```
File file = new File(presentLocation);
 String newLocation = " NEW_LOCATION "; // your new location
 boolean isFileMoved = file.renameTo(new File(newLocation+file.getName())); //tells you whether file is moved or not.

if (isFileMoved) {
  System.out.println("File is successfully moved to "+newLocation);
} else {
   System.out.println("File is not moved to "+newLocation);
}
```

Use this for file moving the file old location to new location and vice-versa. Implement this in your back end with UI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to deep travserse directory for recursive delete.
You can use it to 'show' and navigate.

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at

- [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)
- [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) (although it has a focus on the new features in the Java 7 API, it's still a great reference)